# Можно ли руссифицировать HPLIP?

Tags: hp, linux

Простите за глупый вопрос... Слышал что HPLIP вроде как содержит в себе русскую локализацию, но как её включить???

Answer (score 1):

Думается мне, что hplip берет настройки локализации из переменных окружения. Запустите команду locale, она покажет, какая локаль используется.